# Parse XML document in Perl without knowing its structure

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I'm a beginner in Perl's XML modules, and unfortunately I haven't found a useful solution nor manual for my problem. What I would like to do is to parse any XML file without knowing its structure and hardcoding its tags/nodes. I'd like to get the nodes' name and value as well as attribute for further processing.

At the moment I can only parse XML with hardcoded node names, which means I need to reprogram the parser all the time whenever a new XML file pops up.

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you.

Currently I'm using XML::Simple and the following code:

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple->XMLin( $list_file );
foreach my $xmls (@{$xml->{channel}->{item}}) {
  if (exists $xmls->{title}) { };
  if (exists $xmls->{value}) { };
  if (exists $xmls->{category}) { };
  if (exists $xmls->{description}) { };
}
```

Comment: Which module are you using (e.g. XML dom)? Also, consider sharing what you've tried so far, the Perl code, that is - even if it didn't work out.

Comment: You could use XML::Simple and iterate through its output.

Comment: XML::Simple is the hardest module to use, especially if you don't know the structure in advance (which can be mitigated with `ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => []`)

Answer (score 1):

Any tree-based parser would do. When using XML::LibXML, `$element->childrenNodes` returns the an element's children, and `$element->attributes` returns the an element attributes and xmlns declarations. You can find out if the type of node a child is (element, text, comment, etc) using `$node->nodeType`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
use XML::Simple;
use strict;

my $list_file = 'myfile.xml';
my $xml = XMLin($list_file);

sub identify{
  if(ref $_[0] eq 'HASH'){
    my (@nodes, @attributes);
    foreach(keys %{$_[0]}){
      if(ref $_[0]->{$_} eq 'HASH'){
        push @nodes, $_;
      }else{
        push @attributes, $_;
      }
    }
    if(@nodes){
      print "Nodes:\n";
      print "  $_\n" foreach @nodes;
    }
    if(@attributes){
      print "Attributes: Name => Value\n";
      print "  $_ => ".$_[0]->{$_}."\n" foreach @attributes;
    }
  }else{
    print 'The given element is not a node';
  }
}

identify($xml);
```

Comment: Looks great, thank you, but unfortunately it lists the main nodes and attributes only.